# Probability that sum is divisible by $n$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Let $k,n$ be positive integers such that $k< n$. Show that if $k$ integers are selected from the set  $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ then the probability that their sum is divisible by $n$ is $\dfrac1n$. Also note that $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Not sure how to do this. Looks hard.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Let k,n be positive integers such that k<n. Show that if k integers are selected from the set  {1,2,3,...,n} then the probability that their sum is divisible by n is 1/n.Also note that gcd(k,n)=1. When I post this the full question doesn't come. I am using app and it's not working properly.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I have attempted to edit your question (pending review from someone with higher reputation) so that it's all visible.  Next question:  what have you tried so far?

Comment: @user496230 From the data I suppose we have $k\le n$.

Comment: @user496230 Let try to start with a simple case, as for example $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that is $n=5$ to see how it works.

Comment: Where did the question come from and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is from Ivan nivens book on number theory. I don't think I have anything significant to say about this problem.

Comment: $\sum x_k = r mod n$ then adding 1 mod n will make sum of elements of S congruent to r+k mod n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ${\rm gcd}(k,n)=1$ there are $u$, $v\in{\mathbb Z}$ with
$uk+vn=1$, in particular an $u\in[n]$ such that $$ku=1\quad({\rm mod} \ n)\ .$$
Let $P_k:={[n]\choose k}$ be the set of all  $k$-subsets of $[n]$, and for any $A\in P_k$ denote by $\sigma(A)$ the sum of its elements, modulo $n$. Consider now the map
$$T:\quad P_k\to P_k,\qquad A\mapsto\{x+u\,|\, x\in A\}$$
which adds $u$ to each element of $A$. It follows that $$\sigma\bigl(T(A)\bigr)=\sigma(A)+ku=\sigma(A)+1\ .$$
Together with $T^n={\rm id}$ this allows to conclude that for all $A\in P_k$ the orbit of $A$ under $T$ has  $n$ elements $A_i$, and exactly one of these has $\sigma(A_i)=0$.

Comment: Thanks looks like this is imitating McKay's proof of Cauchy theorem in group theory

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $S$ is a subset containing $k$ integers, what happens when you transform $S$ by adding $1\bmod n$ to each of its elements?